# Push Duplicate key data on key array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have this data structure. I have used the underscorejs but could not find way to that like the below structure

```
var data = [{"5+":2},{"3-5":0},{"1-3":1},{"0.5":0},{"<30":0},{"5+":1},{"3-5":1},{"1-3":0},{"0.5":0},{"<30":0},{"5+":3},{"3-5":0},{"1-3":3},{"0.5":0},{"<30":0}];
var groupArr = [];
##loop through the data##
data.forEach(function(item){
  ##find the keys ##
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  var obj = {};   
  obj[keys] = [];
  ##push the data to object keys array##
  obj[keys].push(item[keys])   
  groupArr.push(obj)
})
```

By using this data structure I want something like this structure

```
[{"5+":[2,1,3]},{"3-5":[0,1,0]},{"1-3":[1,0,,3]},{"0.5":[0,0,0]},{"<30":[0,0,0]}]
```

As I have tried everything but could not find the solution any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can there be multiple keys in the objects? @user3565243

Comment: yes there can be multiple keys

Answer (score 0):

The first part converts the list of objects to a single object, where the keys are each of the unique keys from the list of objects and the values for each key are joined as an array:

```
{
  "5+": [2,1,3],
  "3-5": [0,1,0]
  ...
}
```

Since this is not the format you wanted, the second part converts this object into a list of objects by looping over each key and creating a new object from it.

```js
var data = [{"5+":2},{"3-5":0},{"1-3":1},{"0.5":0},{"<30":0},{"5+":1},{"3-5":1},{"1-3":0},{"0.5":0},{"<30":0},{"5+":3},{"3-5":0},{"1-3":3},{"0.5":0},{"<30":0}];

// create object with all the values joined together in lists.
var map = data
  .reduce(function (map, obj)  {
    var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    // checks if the key allready exits in the new object. 
    // If it does we push a new value into the array,
    // otherwise we create a new property with a list with one value.
    map[key] ?
      map[key].push(obj[key]):
      map[key] = [obj[key]];
    return map;
  }, {});

// convert above result to a list with objects.
var newFormat = Object.keys(map)
  .map(function (key) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = map[key];
    return obj;
  })

console.log(newFormat)
```

Comment: Thanks you are a life saver.

Comment: where you joining the values altogather

Comment: Edited the answer.